# From Java Developer to DevOps and will devops die?

Tags: terminology

Hi all :) I want to switch from java developer to devops because i want to work something more interesting. I know that as a devops i will have to code but beside that i hope i will learn some new things like server administration, CI, CD, networking and a lot of new stuff. I have been asking my self many times but with no answer... will devops die around all this AI stuff. I think that server administration profession can disappear but for devops... i`m not sure. What do you think ? And is it a good idea to switch professions (hope some of you have done this already) ?

Answer (score 3):

> I want to switch from java developer to devops because i want to work something more interesting.

There is no need to *switch*, in IT, generally. You can just add more and more stuff to your toolkit over the years and decades. Just because your new job description is "DevOps" instead of "Java" does not mean that you somehow immediately forget your Java background.

Hunting for something more interesting is always good. It means more learning. You will very likely (hopefully) alternate between hunting for something and deepening that something for your whole life.

> will devops die

Yes, of course it will. *Everything* dies. I have no idea how the IT world will look in 20 years, but one certainty is that it will not look like today.

> around all this AI stuff

Huh? What AI stuff? There is no AI. Machine learning has nothing whatsoever to do with AI, it's just the "next" technique. It's not like Matrix-style AIs take server administration jobs from us, or like AIs build our OpenShift servers.

> I think that server administration profession can disappear

Not for a *long* time. People forget that below the virtualized stuff (VMs, containers, etc.) there still are the same technologies as always, requiring people who know how to manage the basic systems. Sure, it will get different, but not disappear for any time soon.

> I have been asking my self many times

You are overthinking this. Pick a DevOps technique, anyone which seems interesting to you, download some stuff, and just tinker around with it at home for a bit. Or find a nice little project at work. You'll find out in no time whether it is your thing or not. Nothing about DevOps is particularly "special" or "magic" or a totally "different" thing.

Comment: Well put! I would agree that in general, IT/development is not about "switching positions" but rather building your skill set one by one and enhancing those skills piece by piece :)